# Document number regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to find a regular expression for bolivian document numbers:

1234567 LP or 1234567LP

I tried using \w?\s?, but it accepts special characters, like * or %. There isn't a defined number of digits (6 to 8 digits) or letters (2 to 3 letters). It can has one or none white space character.

Any suggestion?
Regards.

Comment: It is a valid document number in Bolivia. What is ICAO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
\b[0-9]{6,8} ?[A-Z]{2,3}\b
```

*(if you want to check a whole string, you must add anchors (`^` and `$`) at the begining and at the end of the pattern. Then word boundaries are no more useful).* Example:

```
^[0-9]{6,8} ?[A-Z]{2,3}$
```

Comment: I tried, but it accepts special characters after the expression: 1234567 SC%

Comment: @RogerVaca: and the notice in italic? : `^[0-9]{6,8} ?[A-Z]{2,3}$`

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\d{6,8} ?[A-Za-z]{2,3}$");
```

Comment: @SimonBelanger Made it more explicit, I think it should work.

Comment: `[A-z]` is different from `[A-Za-z]` or `(?i)[a-z]` see the unicode table in wikipedia.